# Bootstrap grid not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to align an image and text element to be adjacent to each other using the code below. However, the text is currently below the image. Can someone please explain to me how to get the text aligned to the side of the image using bootstrap grid?

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
 <div class = "jumbotron">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
      <img src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSob_6cmEpG703Y4LtxHwGyfnJCi8Dul4Cvg78-73EDQY9bP8hf">
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6">
      <p>Insert blurb here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of bootstrap ? Imported correctly ? Also, remove the dot before container-fluid

Comment: Open console and look for `404` errors

Comment: `<div class = ".container-fluid">` is incorrect - remove the `.`

Comment: why you use dot before `container-fluid` ?

Comment: First change  this `<div class = ".container-fluid">` to this  `<div class = "container-fluid">`

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/5tpa4nw3/

Comment: Check that your window or viewport width is not below 1024px

Comment: I think your code works but your columns have just collapsed because of the viewport width being too small

Comment: I put your code into a JSFiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17095/... alter the width of the result panel and you will see what happens as the panel gets bigger or smaller

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSob_6cmEpG703Y4LtxHwGyfnJCi8Dul4Cvg78-73EDQY9bP8hf" />
</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <p>Insert blurb here</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of bootstrap. It should show image aligned to text as you want. But your first class selector ".container-fluid" should not have period "." character.

Answer (score 0):

try the below html code it may help you.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSob_6cmEpG703Y4LtxHwGyfnJCi8Dul4Cvg78-73EDQY9bP8hf" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <p>Insert blurb here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give .pull-left class  to  having image and .pull-right to div having text and give .pull-right to image

here is the code

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "jumbotron">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-md-6 pull-left">
                        <img class="pull-right" src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSob_6cmEpG703Y4LtxHwGyfnJCi8Dul4Cvg78-73EDQY9bP8hf">
                    </div>
                    <div class = "col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <p>Insert blurb here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```